# How to use unoconv -h from PHP file?

Tags: php, exec

My server is centos6.5 +apache.
I want use php to start unoconv,but when i use exec unoconv it does not work.

I first used 
`exec('unoconv -h');`

which can not work in PHP, but 
it can work on server, when I input `unoconv -h`.

Secondly, I looked for help in [github](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv/issues/87#issuecomment-18800070)
and change my code to

`exec('sudo -u unoconv /usr/bin/unoconv -h');`

It can not work in PHP, but 
it can work on server, when I input this:

`sudo -u unoconv /usr/bin/unoconv -h`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

echo exec('unoconv -h'); flush output command to stdout. Root directory "/" for Apache is /var/www/localhost, /var/www/localhost/htdocs, or subdomain etc. Not a root directory of system. Apache is running under etc www-data not a root. Command unoconv not need root permissions. Sorry for my English.

Comment: but when i use echo shell_exec('ls /usr/bin');
it will print correct things,if "/" is mean /var/www/localhost,
why does it print correct thing?

Comment: "ls" is running as ordinary command, for it is root directory, system directory. But shell_exec('/usr/bin/ls /usr/bin') not work, for Apache is root directory /var/www/... OK?